# Defining integer parameter in parameters.yml in Symfony

Tags: validation, symfony

I have a numeric parameter in the symfony's parameters.yml file and I have a configuration class in my bundle where I validate that the parameter is an integer, but I get the following error in the validation proccess:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidTypeException]    
Invalid type for path "page_size". Expected int, but got string.
```

Is there a way to specify the parameter type in the parameters.yml file?

**EDIT**

parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    ...
    list_page_size: 15
    ...
```

config.yml:

```
...
example:
    page_size: %list_page_size%
...
```

Configuration.php:

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('example');

        $rootNode->children()

            // Some code here
            ->integerNode('page_size')
                ->defaultValue(15)
            ->end()
            // More code here

        ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I have discovered that the exception is thrown in the `prepend()` method in the bundle extension file (DependencyInjection/ExampleExtension.php), but the error is not thrown in the `load` method of the same file. It seems like if the parameters.yml file was not loaded at prepend method execution time.

Comment: Can you post your config class and your parameters.yml file?

Comment: If I write `page_size: 15` directly in the config.yml file, it runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is simply because the `is_int` check fails.

A simple solution would be to add a normalization step like:

```
// Some code here
->integerNode('page_size')
    ->beforeNormalization()
        ->ifString()
        ->then(function ($val) { return strval(intval($val)) === $val ? intval($val) : $val; })
    ->end()
    ->defaultValue(15)
->end()
// More code here
```

Also take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#normalization

Answer (score 0):

If you entered something like :

```
page_size: "10"
```

Then it's a normal behavior.
You should not use " :

```
page_size: 10
```

Comment: That's what I have and it doesn't run.